# Empty python request body

Tags: django, python-requests

I am sending the below payload to the test api as shown but am getting an empty body. Please help. I have checked and I cant see where the problem is.

```
import requests 
#(version 2.20.1)
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/',
              json={'event_ref_id': 'PZpHoGrGKbIEv', 'member_no': 'mb001', 'action': 'course_registration'},
              headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

My Django endpoint is very simple as shown below but an getting an empty body

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def get_test(request):
    print(request.body)
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    print(body)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Why API print body is

```
b'{}'
{}
```

Comment: You don't return anything from response. You need `return Response(body, status=...)`

Comment: @ayuka you want request.data, not request.body

Comment: request.data is empty . { }